# Behavior of conditional statement in the body of switch case (C language)

Tags: c, ternary-operator, operator-precedence, assignment-operator, conditional-operator

The code snippet below works fine as it is but if I want to assign a value to retv in the second part of the conditional statement it throws a compiler error. I am using GCC C compiler.
Can anyone explain why?

*Code*

```
typedef enum {
mt1 = 23,
mt2 = 43,
mt3 = 53
} mts;

int getmt(mts value, int sign) {
    int retv = -1;
    switch(value) {
        case mt1: sign == 0? retv=1 : retv; //ERROR if retv=0 
                  break;
        case mt2: break;
        case mt3: break;
        default: break;
    }
    return retv;
}
int main(void)
{
    printf("val:%d\n", getmt(mt1, 0));
    printf("val:%d\n", getmt(mt2, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

*Error*

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
         case mt1: sign == 0? retv=1 : retv=0; break;
```

Comment: Why are you using a tristate operator in place of an `if`? It hurts readability and does not make it any faster nor better.

Comment: The ternary operator is very much overused, it makes code harder to read and understand and maintain. Use proper `if` statements instead. If I understand your code correctly what you want is simply `if (sign == 0) retv = 1;`

Comment: conditional **expression**: `retv=(sign==0)?1:retv;`

Comment: By the way, your error message doesn't match the code you show! It's important to make sure that you show us a proper [mcve] that replicates the error you get, and show use that code together with the full and complete error output (copy-pasted as text) from that exact code. And please read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 3):

That's because the ternary conditional has higher operator precedence than `=`. It will compile like this:

```
case mt1: sign == 0 ? (retv = 1) : (retv = 0);
```

Comment: `retv = 0` changes the semantics, I think the purpose is to leave `retv` unmodified in that case.

Comment: I think that was OP's intention. Given the comment `//ERROR if retv=0`, I think he wanted it to be like that, but it wouldn't compile that way. I could be misunderstanding this, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in defining the conditional operator in C and C++.

In C the operator is defined like

```
logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

and the conditional operator has higher precedence then the assignment operator.

Thus this expression statement

```
sign == 0? retv = 1 : retv = 0;
```

is processed like

```
( sign == 0? retv = 1 : retv ) = 0;
```

To avoid the error You could rewrite the original expression more simpler as

```
retv = sign == 0? 1 : 0;
```

or even simpler

```
retv = sign == 0;
```

In C++ this operator is defined like

```
logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

So in C++ this expression statement

```
sign == 0? retv = 1 : retv = 0;
```

will be valid.:)